# Python prevent subprocess from consuming keypress

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script starting an .exe program in Windows. I want to be able to terminate this program by pressing "ESC". But I can't see the keypress in my Python program, it is read by the .exe program and consumed. How can I start the .exe program so that it does not read from stdin/keyboard. I do not need to send any keyboard commands to the .exe program.

This is the code I use:

```
 pid = subprocess.Popen(functionCall)
    while ((pid.poll()) or (pid.returncode == None)):
        if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch()==chr(27):
            print("ESC detected")
            pid.kill()
            pid.wait()
        else:
            print("Sleep")
            time.sleep(1)
    print("Exit while")
```

Comment: Since .exe is the active application you are not going to get keystrokes in your program. Handle ESC in your .exe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks lite my problem wasn't the subprocess catching the keypress. But my handling of reading the keypress and analysing key value. Sorry for disturbing.

Solution to my problem:

```
 msvcrt.getch().decode()==chr(27)
```

instead of:

```
msvcrt.getch()==chr(27)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** possible.

The parent process (*in this case Python*) has no direct control (*other than to send signals and read from stdout/stderr and send to stdin*) over the subprocess.

You will need to handle this in the `.EXE` (*Windows executable*) itself; assuming you have the source code and **can** modify it.

Comment: Thanks for an answear, seams my problem wasn't the subprocess but my handling of the keypress.